# SSIS Derived Column Expression to skip null/blank value and take the next digits of string value

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, derived-column

I am very new to SSIS and I am performing a task where I have to take the flat-file text document and then derive the columns with specific digit lengths. For eg, lines in the text document are:

```
101001A00000000000000309493020111139                                     112
101001A00000000000000309493020111139112
```

I am writing derived columns such that certain digit lengths become my columns

| Expression | Derived Column Name |
| --- | --- |
| `substring([column 0],1,3)` | record1 |
| `substring([column 0],4,6)` | record1 |

I want to skip the null values here in order to take the value 112
how do write an expression for this?
For a non-null scenario, I can proceed with the same substring function but I want to handle these blank spaces or `null` values too.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You should use two derived column transformations in that scenario:

1. The first is to remove extra blank, you can use the following expression:

```
REPLACE([column 0]," ","")
```

If the word `NULL` is written as a text, you can use the following expression:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([column 0]," ",""),"null","")
```

2. The second derived column transformation takes that output and split the lines into separate columns.